# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, attributes

I do not have a file named numpy.py.
My exact steps are: in Python, Open C:\Adrian\Python37\Lib\numpy-1.11.2\setup.py, I run this module:

```
>>> 
=========== RESTART: C:\Adrian\Python37\Lib\numpy-1.11.2\setup.py ===========
Running from numpy source directory.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list_int = [8, 3, 34, 111]
>>> a_int = np.array(list_int)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
a_int = np.array(list_int)
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array'
```

Comment: Could you show us your code, please?

Comment: What do you mean by open .....\setup.py? You shouldn't be doing that. Once numpy is properly installed you should be able to import numpy by opening a shell anywhere in the directory tree.

Comment: Its an online course. The code looks fine on the website but I need to implement it on my com: Chapter 4.3.1 Create NumPy arrays from lists, an overview of array properties

The main NumPy library is numpy which we need to import to be able to use NumPy functionality.
import numpy as np
# First, we will use a simple list of 4 integer numbers to create an array
list_int = [8, 3, 34, 111]
a_int = np.array(list_int)
a_int
array([8,3,34,111])

Comment: I solved it! I had to install numpy properly

Answer (score 1):

In English : I had encountered the same problem as you, and as for me the cause of the problem was that I had create a test file with the name of numpy.py in the root of my project question to make tests. So by importing the numpy library, I had to know this bug because python imported my test file instead of the library.

So you have to start by checking whether the name of your project or a file other than the library has the name of the library to import. be sure that none of your files with the name of your project respond to a name from a library.

Answer (score 0):

Reported symptom is:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a_int = np.array(list_int)
...
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array'
```

This can't possibly happen if numpy is correctly installed.

The OP explains that re-installing numpy properly on his machine solves the symptom.

Answer (score 0):

Even I created a file with name "numpy.py". This file is imported itself.
changed the file name.

Answer (score 0):

I spent way to much time on this from misspelling array

```
np.arrray(list)
```